Problem to execute php artisan install:api
Hi I am trying to create one apirest in laravel, I have created the project, then I executed in console line the comand:
php artisan install:api

And generate me the follow error:
There are no commands defined in the "install" namespace.

Already use the comand:
php artisan clear-compiled

I reinstalled composer, but the problem persist.
Please somebody can help me, thanks.

Are you sure that you are using Laravel 11?what is your current PHP version?
